# What object should I lock on when I am passing a Collection<Foo> into a separate class?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Please refer to [UML](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37403003@N08/3745217702/)

The Connection class's constructor initializes its *foos* member via

```
foos = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList<Foo>(10) );
```

When Connection#start() is invoked, it creates an instance of Poller (while passing the *foos* reference into Poller's constructor) & Poller is started (Poller is a Runnable).

**Question**: The *Poller* thread will add to & remove objects from the list based on external events. Periodically clients will invoke *Connection#snapshot()* to retrieve the list. Since the implementation within Poller will perform a check to avoid duplicates during additions, it is not thread safe.

e.g. implemention of Poller#run

```
if( _foos.indexOf( newFoo ) == -1 )
{
    _foos.add( newFoo );
}
```

What can I synchronize on in *Connection* as well as *Poller* to order to be thread safe?

Comment: You can embed images in your question, you don't need to use an external link.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at CopyOnWriteArrayList as a replacement for the ArrayList in the example above.  That way you won't need to synchronize on anything since you have a thread safe collection out of the box, so to speak...

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

From the API CopyOnWriteArrayList is...

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in
>   which all mutative operations (add,
>   set, and so on) are implemented by
>   making a fresh copy of the underlying
>   array.

n.b. This is only a viable solution if the number of traversals outweigh the number of additions/updates to the collection.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

There is a clean solution using interfaces and anonymous inner classes.

In the **Connection** class add the following:

```
public static interface FooWorker {
    void onFoos(List<Foo> list);
}

public synchronized void withFoosSafely(FooWorker worker) {
    worker.onFoos(foos);
}
```

In the **Poller** class do the following:

```
public void doWork() {
    connection.withFoosSafely(new FooWorker() {
         public void onFoos(List<Foo> list) {
              /// add, remove and change the list as you see fit
              /// everything inside this method is thread-safe
         }
    });
}
```

It requires a bit of additional code (no closures yet in Java) but it guarantees thread safety and also makes sure clients don't need to take care of locking - less potential bugs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might return a new List from `snapshot()`:

```
public List<Foo> snapshot() {
    return new ArrayList<Foo>(foos);
}
```

Given that you're returning a "snapshot", it seems OK to me that the list is guaranteed to be up-to-date only at the moment it gets returned.

If you're expecting clients to add/remove members from `foos`, then you'd probably need to expose those operations as methods on `Connection`.

Comment: Clients are not alllowed to add/remove from the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not getting the point, it seems `Connection#snapshot` should be synchronized on `this` (or on `_foos`) and so does the code block of `Poller` that manages `Connection._foos`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Poller is a separate class, it is not an inner class of Connection!

Comment: That does not stop it from having a synchronized block on Connection. I am sure it has a reference to the Connection it manager, else how could it manage?